# Closing all app windows when using Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am learning to write JavaScript in Electron. I have two windows. A main window and a child window. When the main window closes selecting the X on a windows computer I want it to close the entire app including the child window. The line below works on a Mac PC.

```
mainWindow.on('closed', () => app.quit());
```

What is the proper way of doing the same thing for windows pcs.

Comment: So you're saying that doesn't work on Windows? What happens instead? Any errors or other feedback?

Comment: When you hit the X on the main window the child window stays

Comment: only if i actually select quit in my file menu does it actually close both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`app.quit()` is the correct function for doing this.

Quote from the documentation (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md)

> Try to close all windows. The `before-quit` event will be emitted first. If all windows are successfully closed, the `will-quit` event will be emitted and by default the application will terminate.
>
> This method guarantees that all `beforeunload` and unload event handlers
>   are correctly executed. It is possible that a window cancels the
>   quitting by returning `false` in the `beforeunload` event handler.

You could correct the behavior in Windows if you close the app directly on button click, instead of closing the window -> listening to the event -> and quitting the app

```
const app = require('electron').remote.app;
const close = document.getElementById('myCloseButton');
close.on('click',function(){
  app.quit();
});
```

Note: `app.exit()` also exists but it does not send the events mentioned above, so it should only be used if necessary.

Comment: It is possible that a window cancels the quitting by returning false in the beforeunload event handler. 
How can I override the beforeUnload events of all windows, so they cannot cancel?

Answer (score 2):

I handle it like so within main.js:

```
// create two windows
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
let backgroundWindow = new BrowserWindow();
```

Expose a function to the renderer (in this case "mainWindow") to shut down the app:

```
 exports.closeAppWindow = function(){
    backgroundWindow.close();
    mainWindow.close();
}
```

As the quoted documentation above states:

> If all windows are successfully closed, the will-quit event will be emitted and by default the application will terminate.

The app then shuts down since both windows have been closed.