# Closing all windows from within the browser in Electron 28.2.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Looked at:

- [Closing all app windows when using Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589278/closing-all-app-windows-when-using-electron)
- [ElectronJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "BrowserWindow" / "getCurrentWindow" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971120/electronjs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-browserwindow-getcurre)

I'm using Electron 28.2.2 and all of the above is outdated for me (no way to enable `remote`).

`require("electron")` is returning `undefined` for `remote` and `app` in the browser window. Here is my browser initialization:

```js
const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 640,
    menuBarVisible: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
    },
});
window.loadFile("src/index.html");
```

Here is my browser script:

```js
const { app: application } = require("electron");

export class HeaderNavigation {
    constructor() {
        // Close button
        this.closeButton = document.querySelector("#navigationBar #close");
        this.closeButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
            application.quit();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when exchanging messages between `ipcMain` from the Electron process and `ipcRenderer` from the browser window.

*Electron process*

```js
const { app: application, ipcMain } = require("electron");

ipcMain.on("request-close", e => {
    application.quit();
});
```

*Browser window*

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

ipcRenderer.sendSync("request-close");
```